# Does imposing a boundary condition undermine a Sobolev embedding result?

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, partial-differential-equations, normed-spaces, sobolev-spaces

Does a boundary condition undermine a Sobolev embedding result?

I assume imposing a boundary condition on the functions in the space $W^{m,p}(\Omega)$ does not change its embedding into any larger space; for any changes on the boundary, the function still belong to that same class of functions.

Comment: Keep in mind the boundary condition may not make sense in the embedding space. E.g., $H^1_0 \subset \subset L^2$, but there is no notion of zero trace in $L^2$.

Answer (score 2):

Imposing boundary conditions means you are considering subspaces of $W^{m,p}(\Omega)$, thus all the embedding results transfer. You only have to make sure that you end up with closed subspaces, so that the new space is again a Banach space.

Comment: How would you know if the resulting subspace is dense. For instance, take $H^2_0$ and $H^2\cap H^1_0$ as subspaces of $H^2$. Are they closed?